# xamarin forms Image does not show up

Tags: c#, image, xamarin, xamarin.forms, display

I have a simple app that has a PicListPage (picture list).  The xaml and code behind allow picking a picture from the Android emulator gallery or from taking a picture.

The selected picture (or new picture) does not show up in an Image control.  I have not been able to find a solution through a web search.  This code was copied from a tutorial. Putting a breakpoint at the NewImage.Source line shows that there is a non-null value for the currentimage.

Any help would be appreciated.  The MS Xamarin Forums won't allow me to register or log in so I can't ask the question there.

Jim Durbin
durbinjw@gmail.com

Here is the XAML

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="MyStuff.PicListPage">
    <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
        <ToolbarItem x:Name="selectImageButton"
            Text="Select Image"
            Command="{Binding SelectImageCommand}"/>
        <ToolbarItem x:Name="takePicButton"
            Text="Take Picture"
            Command="{Binding TakePictureCommand}"
            CommandParameter="{Binding NewImage}"/>
        <ToolbarItem x:Name="deleteButton"
            Text="Delete"
            Command="{Binding DeletePictureCommand}"
            CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedImage}"/>
    </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ContentPage.Content>
            <StackLayout>
                <Label Text="Picture List page"
           HorizontalOptions="Center"
           FontSize="Large"
           FontAttributes="Bold"/>
            <Frame BorderColor="Black"
                   WidthRequest="350"
                   HeightRequest="350"
                   Margin="10,0,10,0">
                <FlexLayout Direction="Row">
                    **<Image x:Name="NewImage"**
                           IsVisible="true"
                           Aspect="AspectFit"
                           Source="{Binding NewImmage, Mode=TwoWay}"
                           Margin="10,0,10,0"
                           WidthRequest="350"
                           HeightRequest="350"
                           HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                           VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                    </Image>
                </FlexLayout>
            </Frame>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Here is the code behind - first the command code for selecting a picture

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace MyStuff.ViewModel.Commands
{
    public class SelectImageCommand : ICommand
    {
        private PicListPageVM viewmodel;

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

        public SelectImageCommand(PicListPageVM viewmodel)
        {
            this.viewmodel = viewmodel;
        }
        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return true;
        }

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            viewmodel.SelectImage();
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the ViewModel code snippet that copies the image from the emulated Gallery which has 5 pictures in it.

```
    using MyStuff.Model;
using MyStuff.ViewModel.Commands;
using Plugin.Media;
using Plugin.Media.Abstractions;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace MyStuff.ViewModel
{
    public class PicListPageVM : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public ObservableCollection<PicList> PicLists { get; set; }
        public TakePictureCommand TakePictureCommand { get; set; }
        public SelectImageCommand SelectImageCommand { get; set; }
        public DeletePictureCommand DeletePictureCommand { get; set; }

        private Image newimage;
        public Image NewImage
        {
            get { return newimage; }
            set
            {
                newimage = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("NewImage");
            }
        }

        public PicListPageVM()
        {
            SelectImageCommand = new SelectImageCommand(this);
            TakePictureCommand = new TakePictureCommand(this);
            DeletePictureCommand = new DeletePictureCommand(this);
            NewImage = new Image();
            NewImage.IsOpaque = false;
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

            public async void SelectImage()
        {
            await CrossMedia.Current.Initialize();
            if (!CrossMedia.Current.IsPickPhotoSupported)
            {
                await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Information", "Can't select pictures on this device", "OK");
                return;
            }
            var mediaoptions = new PickMediaOptions()
            {
                PhotoSize = PhotoSize.Small
            };
            var selectedImageFile = await CrossMedia.Current.PickPhotoAsync(mediaoptions);
            if (selectedImageFile == null)
            {
                await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Information", "No image selected.", "OK");
                return;
            }
            **var currentimage = ImageSource.FromStream(() => selectedImageFile.GetStream());
            NewImage.Source = currentimage;**
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

first, you misspelt the name of your property ("NewImage") in the binding (**TwoWay** binding also doesn't make sense here)

```
<Image x:Name="NewImage" Source="{Binding NewImmage, Mode=TwoWay}" .. />
```

second, in your VM `NewImage` is of type `Image`, which is not right.  `Image` is a UI control, not a data type.  Use `string` instead

```
    private string newimage;
    public string NewImage
    {
        get { return newimage; }
        set
        {
            newimage = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("NewImage");
        }
    }
```

finally, when you select your image set the VM property to the image path

```
NewImage = selectedImageFile.AlbumPath;
```

Comment: Hi @Jason.  Thanks..  
First I was blind to the spelling error after looking at it repeatedly.   
That is fixed and I removed the mode entirely. (Is that correct?)  
Second,  the selected image still does not show up. 
Changing the NewImage data type seems logical for the binding.  
Is setting the string property NewImage to selectedImageFile.AlbumPath 
supposed to cause the image to be displayed by itself? 
Is it also necessary to set the Source? Maybe the code is missing 
another setting? 
Sorry to sound so dense. I am relatively new to Xamarin.

Comment: Hi @Jason.  Played with it a bit and it now runs ok.  Had to change  NewImage = selectedImageFile.AlbumPath;  to NewImage = selectedImageFile.Path;

Comment: @JWDurbin Hi, if have solved that, remember to mark the answer when you have time. It will be helpful for others to know the solution.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is resolved.  Thanks to @Jason and a little further hacking.  The key issues were 1) a typo in the binding  2) The binding needed to point to a property that had datatype string instead of an Image UI element - which in turn pointed to a file path and 3) setting the bound string to point to the selectedImageFile.Path rather than to selectedImageFile.AlbumPath.